# Functions of multivariables

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm having issues with calculating:

$\lim (x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ for $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{2x^2 +3y^2}$$
Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $$|\frac{x^2y}{2x^2 +3y^2}|=|\frac{y}{2 +3(\frac{x}{y})^2}|=\frac{|y|}{2 +3(\frac{x}{y})^2}<\frac{|y|}{2}\longrightarrow_{y\longrightarrow0}0$$
so $$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{\frac{x^2y}{2x^2 +3y^2}}=0$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would it be correct to say: $$ \frac {x^2 y} {2x^2 +3y^2} < \frac {|y| (2x^2 +3y^2)} {2x^2 +3y^2} = |y| $$ and use that for the larger function

Comment: It will not prove what you want. the limit might be negative or might not exsist. In my answer I proved that the limit of the absoulte value is zero, so limit is zero. If you liked my asnwer then please rate it.

Comment: Yes I know that I still need to show that the limit is 0. But is that claim above valid? And don't worry lol. I'll be giving best answer to you as no one else has really helped.

Comment: @Mathew I think this is a very nice answer and you should have already upvoted as I think it is really helpful, no matter if you *accept* afterwards this or any other answer. I don't understand why you say you "still have to show the limit is zero": this answer already did that!

Comment: I can't upvote yet because I'm new and it was him that said you "still have to show that the limit is 0", not me. I'm just asking if it's correct to say what I said above...

Answer (score 0):

A hint: Consider the simpler problem where the two coefficients in the denominator are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Consider using the corollary of sandwich theorem because all the terms in the denominator are positive ...

Answer (score 0):

Another idea: use polar coordinates, and observe we have then that

$\;(x,y)\to(0,0)\iff x^2+y^2=r^2\to0\iff r\to0\;$, so

$$\frac{x^2y}{2x^2+3y^2}=r\frac{\cos^2\theta\sin\theta}{2+\sin^2\theta}\xrightarrow[r\to0]{}0$$